# How can I parse HTML code with "html written" URL in Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am starting to program in Python, and have been reading a couple of posts where they say that I should use an HTML parser to get an URL from a text rather than re.

I have the source code which I got from `page.read()` with the `urllib` and `urlopen`.

Now, my problem is that the parser is removing the url part from the text.

Also, if I had read correctly, `var = page.read()`, `var` is stored as a string?

How can I tell it to give me the text between 2 "tags"? The URL is always in between `flv=` and `;` so and as such it doesn't start with `href` which is what the parsers look for, and it doesn't contain `http://` either.

I have read many posts, but it seems they all look for ``href in the code.

Do I have it all completely wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: is your request returning html?  if `flv=` is an attribute of an html tag then you should be able to easily use a parse to retrieve the value

Comment: the request is returning html. The URL inside the code is http%3A%3A... I'll try looking more into flv=, thanks!

Comment: give us a snippet of the html you are dealing with and the expected url hope to extract.

Comment: You only read the HTML source of the page; you are not parsing anything just yet. Did you take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing your own search / grab. In psuedocode, it would look a little like this:

```
find location of 'flv=' in HTML = location_start
find location of ';' in HTML = location_end
grab everything in between:   HTML[location_start : location_end]
```

You should be able to implement this in python.

Good luck!